# Symfony 2 - Adding user roles under the ROLE_USER

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, roles

I'm trying to create a new role in Symfony 2 below the default USER_ROLE (that role would have limited write access to some features). I am using FOSUserBundle.

I've written the following security settings so far but my ROLE_DEMO users still get the ROLE_USER.

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_DEMO:        []
        ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_DEMO]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Is it possible to create a role under the ROLE_USER in Symfony 2. If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A even shorter solution i came up with was to override the `const ROLE_DEFAULT` at the beginning of my owner `User` class.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /** 
     * Override FOSUserBundle User base class default role.
     */
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_DEMO';

    [...]
}
```

That way i did not even have to override the FOS user bundle `getRoles()` method.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using FOSUserBundle, it will give all users the `ROLE_USER` by default. `ROLE_USER` is present on every single hydrated user under the default FOSUserBundle setup (although not in the database). You could override that implementation by defining your own `getRoles()` method on your own `User` class. Or change the default role to `ROLE_NONE` (it doesn't really matter what). Or just avoid using `ROLE_USER` and come up with another role name for your actual users.

This is from the default `User` implementation

```
/* FOS\UserBundle\Model\User */
...
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

Comment: I am. In the database though, the user only has the ROLE_DEMO. I would you recommend to change that ?

Comment: 'ROLE_USER' is present on every single user under the default FOSUserBundle setup (although not in the database). You could override that implementation by defining your own getRoles() method on your own User class. Or change the default role to 'ROLE_NONE' (or whatever). Or just avoid using ROLE_USER and come up with another role name for your actual users.

Comment: Seems fair. Would you mind editing your answer to include that last part of your comment ? I thing its a lot clearer. Tks !

Answer (score 1):

for symfony 3 and 4

use this in you entity User

```
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```