# Does Symfony2 grants de ROLE_USER by default?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My role hierarchy in the security.yml is this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_API:         ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPERVISOR:  ROLE_USER
    ROLE_DIRECTOR:    ROLE_SUPERVISOR
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_DIRECTOR, ROLE_API]
```

And I'm adding a new role called ROLE_RETAILER that has no heritage. So I didn't put it in the role_hierarchy section.

When I log in with a user that only has the ROLE_RETAILER, also the ROLE_USER is granted.

In the database the roles field contains this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:13:"ROLE_RETAILER";}
```

And checking the profiler for the logged user shows:
[image: granted roles]

I need to get rid of that ROLE_USER, or I'll have to rewrite the access control list and modify code from some controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using FOSUserBundle, all users have the ROLE_USER granted by default, even if it isn't stored in the database.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29961147/7505730) for more info on how FOSUserBundle assigns Roles.

Comment: Thanks, I can use the const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_DEFAULT'; ovewritting to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can override it in your custom User class

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need all its features, IMHO FOSUserBundle might be an overkill.

According to the documentation here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

> 1) Initial security.yml Setup (Authentication)

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
```

**Anonymous** is set by default.

Otherwise, you might want to check this tutorial here

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep2/roles-disabling-user

on setting your own default roles handling

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    // allows for chaining
    return $this;
}
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_RETAILER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```